# How to get stdout/stderr in logfiles immediately?

Tags: linux, bash

To run some Python program I use the following bash script:

```
python3 /MyProg.py 0>/dev/null 1>>output_log_file 2>error_log_file
```

However I can get information after the prog is terminated only. When program is running there are not any data in these files.

Can I override this behavior to get log data immediately? My OS is Raspbian.

Comment: if you can edit `MyProg.py` you can call a `flush` on the streams. Otherwise things will only be written when the buffer (4Kb on my machine is full, or if the stream is closed). I don't know if there is a way to tell linux to make the buffer smaller, so it is written more often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the program needs to flush stdout and stderr periodically, via

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is because it uses full buffering instead of line buffering. Try to use `unbuffer` before your bash command and you should get the output on screen immediately.